# Can I use MYSQL spatial extensions with sqlalchemy?

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, geospatial

I am looking for a way to map spatial data to sqlalchemy objects. Does someone can tell me if there is such a way? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you'll want to look at the [GeoAlchemy](https://pypi.org/project/GeoAlchemy/0.7.2) package.

Brings a column type to the table called GeometryColumn.

Filtering is very sqlalchemic also. From the docs:

```
s = session.query(Spot).filter(Spot.geom.kml == '<Point><coordinates>-81.4,38.08</coordinates></Point>').first()
```

It's no further away than a simple `pip install GeoAlchemy`.

Comment: It seems good. I will try it. Here is another question. How can I create a spatial index for the column? Simply add index=True for it? Thanks!

Comment: GeoAlchemy does not support MySQL

Comment: Why is this still the accepted solution when other answers say that GeoAlchemy does not support MySQL?

Comment: Because 2012 vs 2018. :) I can't change which is accepted but I used votes to nudge the now-correct one.

Answer (score 11):

You could create `MySQL` spatial columns with [GeoAlchemy](https://pypi.org/project/GeoAlchemy/), but this package is no longer maintained. It's not possible to do it with [GeoAlchemy2](https://pypi.org/project/GeoAlchemy2/), as it does not support `MySQL` according to the [documentation](https://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Anyway, `GeoAlchemy` is not necessary to use `MySQL` spatial columns in `Python`. You can achieve it by creating the custom `Geometry` class:

```py
from sqlalchemy import func
from sqlalchemy.types import UserDefinedType

class Geometry(UserDefinedType):
    def get_col_spec(self):
        return 'GEOMETRY'

    def bind_expression(self, bindvalue):
        return func.ST_GeomFromText(bindvalue, type_=self)

    def column_expression(self, col):
        return func.ST_AsText(col, type_=self)
```

Then, you can use this custom type inside your model:

```py
your_column = Column(Geometry, nullable=False)
```

Comment: you're looking at geoalchemy 2's docs, not geoalchemy, which supports MySQL: https://geoalchemy.readthedocs.io/